# Is there any way to create full include and inheritance diagrams over the project?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I need to get inheritance diagram of ALL the classes and include diagram of ALL the files in the project. Is there any feature in doxygen to do that?

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. You already get inheritance diagrams for each inheritance tree --  what would a single diagram look like, other than just being each diagram placed side-by-side?

Comment: Yes, I need all inheritance trees in one place. That's the point. Side-by-side would be pretty enough. Is there any way to create such?

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to generate a summary page of diagrams in Doxygen -- you could just look in the directory structure for all the PNGs, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using doxywizard or command line? If you run it from on your project's root directory with the appropriate commandline options, it should generate the includes. I don't recall what those are off the top of my head, but you can take a look at the documentation:
http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/index.html

Usually the defaults are all you need. 
If you are not familiar with doxygen, install one of the GUIs.